# In Java, I am doing a project, and I can compile my code in Eclipse, but anywhere else I get a runtime exception

Tags: java

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Tester 
{

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {

        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
        int cases = reader.nextInt();
        for(int i = 0; i < cases; i++)
        {
            int len = reader.nextInt();
            int ants = reader.nextInt();
            int[] distance = new int[ants];
            for(int j = 0; j < ants; j++)
            {
                distance[j] = reader.nextInt();

            }
            Arrays.sort(distance);
            int longest = len - distance[0];
            int mid = (len / 2);
            int val2 = 0;
            int val1 = 0;
            for(int k = 0; k < distance.length; k++)
            {
                if((mid > distance[k]) && (mid < distance[k + 1]))
                {
                    val1 = distance[k] ;
                    val2 = distance[k + 1];
                }
            }
            int shortest;
            if(val1 > len - val2)
                shortest = val1;
            else
                shortest = len - val2;

            if(i + 1 != cases)
                System.out.println(shortest + " " + longest);
            else
                System.out.print(shortest + " " + longest);


        }

        reader.close();

    }

}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. I don't understand why it works in eclipse, but not anywhere else. It seems by the errors that it is something to do with scanner as the error I get is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:862)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2117)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2076)
    at Tester.main(Tester.java:12)
```

Any help I receive is greatly appreciated. I am quite new to programming and have nobody to receive help from.
The input is:

2
10 3
2 6 7
214 7
11 12 7 13
176 23 191

Comment: A runtime exception is a *runtime exception*, not a *compile-time* exception so it doesn't matter that Eclipse can compile it. Anyways, your Scanner cannot find the element you request with `nextInt`.

Comment: You could provide us with what you enter as System.in?

Comment: I have updated it with the input.

Answer (score 1):

I believe your mistake lies with the nextInt(). I can also observe that you never check if you still have an integer down the line: hasNextInt().

So when you initialize your cases variable, you need to do the hasNextInt() verification:

```
int cases;
if(reader.hasNextInt()){
    cases = reader.nextInt();
}
else{
    cases = 0;
}
```

Also, might I suggest you read this document : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt(int)